# find and delete tuple from list of tuples in C# 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, list, find, tuples

I have created a list of tuples:

```
static List<Tuple<string, string>> Alt;
```

The user adds to this list:

```
Alt.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(tbAlt.Text, ""));
```

What is the best way to find a Tuple based on the first string (i.e. the tbAlt.Text ) and either delete it or modify the second string?

I am new to using Tuples and lists :)

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears the first string must be unique or you would not find a (singular)

Why are you using `List<Tuple<string, string>>`?

Why not `Dictionary<string,string>`?

`Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.ContainsKey` is very very fast.

[Dictionary.ContainsKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx)

Comment: But what if the order of the list matters. Dictionaries can not guarantee the order.

Comment: @RayOldProf If you have a question then post it as a question

Answer (score 3):

Your list of tuples looks much like dictionary. Consider using it instead - `Dictionary<string,string>` . It already has methods for retreiving value by key, deleting it, e.t.c.

If there could be multiple values for the same key, you can use Lookup class.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`List<T>.FindIndex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca.aspx) to find the matching index, then replace as needed.

```
int index = Alt.FindIndex(t => t.Item1 == tbAlt.Text);

if (index != -1)
{
   // Modify
   Alt[index] = Tuple.Create(tbAlt.Text, "NewText");

   // Remove:
   Alt.RemoveAt(index);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Find tuple based on value of first string (`Item1`):

```
var t = Alt.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Item1 == "SomeString");
if(t != null)
{
    // delete
    Alt.Remove(t);
}
```

From comments:

You can't modify value of second item (`Item2`), because tuples are immutable, so you 'll have to remove it and add it again.

Comment: Tuples are immutable - you can't set `Item2`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd386892.aspx  That's why I used `FindIndex` instead of LINQ (so you could replace the entire tuple in the list)

Comment: Ops, thank you @ReedCopsey, it is reasonable if you need to maintain order of tuples, otherwise removing old and adding new tuple should do the trick too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure the list contain your item :

```
Alt.Remove(Alt.First(i => i.Item1 == tbAlt.Text));
```

However, in order to modify a Tuple, you must create a new one.

```
if (Alt.Any(i => i.Item1 == tbAlt.Text))
{
    Alt.Remove(Alt.First(i => i.Item1 == tbAlt.Text));
    Alt.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(tbAlt.Text, "Something New"));
}
```